# Dividing objects in equal parts

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

What are the number of ways of dividing $n_1$ objects of type $1$, $n_2$ objects of type $2,\ldots,n_k$ objects of type $k$ into 2 equal parts?

Note: take $\sum n_i=2n$ so that each part contains $n$ objects.

Comment: can you give a simple example? Not sure what this question is asking and the answer to it didn't help me in understanding the question either.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give two solutions.  One is the generating function, and the other is an exact (but messy) answer using inclusion/exclusion.

First, the problem is equivalent to finding the number of integer solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n$, where $0 \leq x_j \leq n_j$.  This is because we need to select $n$ total items from the $k$ groups, with the restriction that we can't select any more than $n_j$ objects from group $j$, to form the first part.  Once that selection is made, the second part is completely determined.

---

**Generating function.**

Problems of finding the number of integer solutions to an equation subject to certain restrictions are a classic use of generating functions.  In fact, these types of problems are often used to motivate generating functions in introductory combinatorics texts.  (For example, see Tucker's *Applied Combinatorics*.)

Anyway, the generating function is $$f(x) = \prod_{j=1}^k \left(\sum_{i=0}^{n_j} x^i \right).$$
So the answer to your question is the coefficient of $x^n$ in this expression.

But why is this?  Well, the problem of finding the number of integer solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n$, where $0 \leq x_j\leq n_j$, is the same as finding the number of ways to choose integers $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k$ with $0 \leq x_j\leq n_j$ so that we have 
$x^{x_1} x^{x_2} \cdots x^{x_k} = x^n$.  Now, for $x_1$ we can choose the factor to be $x^0$ or $x^1$ or $x^2$, and so forth, up to $x^{n_1}$.  Expressing the "or" as addition, this can be represented as $1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{n_1}$.  Similarly, we can represent the choices for $x_2$ as $1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{n_2}$, and so forth, up to the choices for $x_k$ as $1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{n_k}$.  Now, we need to choose one of the $x_j$'s for each $j$.  Representing "and" by multiplication, we get that the expression $f(x)$ above represents in some sense the different ways to choose the $x_j$'s. Moreover, expanding $f(x)$ in powers of $x$, we can see that any term with $x^n$ encodes a way to choose an $x_1$, an $x_2$, and so forth, so that $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n$.  The coefficient of $x^n$ in $f(x)$ therefore must be the number of solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n$, where $0 \leq x_j\leq n_j$.

---

**Exact answer using inclusion/exclusion.**

The number of non-negative integer solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n$ with no restrictions is $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$.  This is a classic application of the [stars and bars argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29).  Any ordering of $n$ stars and $k-1$ bars determines a solution to this equation, and vice versa.  You just have to select the positions of the bars, and then the stars are in the remaining positions.

Now, let $A_k$ be the set of solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n$ with $x_j \leq n_j$.  We want $$|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \cdots \cap A_k|.$$

To calculate this we can use the [principle of inclusion and exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  We need $|A_j'|$, which is the number of non-negative integer solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n$ with $x_j \geq n_j+1$.  Since there are $n_j+1$ places where we cannot put bars, we have $|A_j'| = \binom{n+k-n_j-2}{k-1}$.  Similarly, $|A_i' \cap A_j'| = \binom{n+k-n_i - n_j-3}{k-1}$, and so forth.

Applying inclusion/exclusion, then, the answer is 
\begin{align}
|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \cdots \cap A_k| = &\binom{n+k-1}{k-1} - \sum_{j=1}^n \binom{n+k-n_j-2}{k-1} + \sum_{j_1 < j_2} \binom{n+k-n_{j_1}  - n_{j_2} -3}{k-1} \\
&- \cdots + (-1)^i \sum_{j_1 < j_2 < \cdots < j_i} \binom{n+k- \sum_{\ell=1}^i n_{j_\ell} - i -1}{k-1} \\ 
       &+ \cdots + (-1)^k \binom{n+k- 2n - k -1}{k-1}.
\end{align}
In practice you won't need to go all the way to the end with the calculations because after a while the binomial coefficient values (such as the last one) will all be $0$.